# using foreign currency signs when converting to currency

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

```
'Declare Variables

Dim decPound As Decimal
Dim decYen As Decimal
Dim decEuro As Decimal

'Calculate
decPound = CDec((CDec(txtDollar.Text) / 1.63))
decEuro = CDec((CDec(txtDollar.Text) / 1.29))
decYen = CDec((CDec(txtDollar.Text) / 0.0095))

'Display
'Pounds
lblPounds.Text = (decPound).ToString("n2")
'Euro
lblEuros.Text = (decEuro).ToString("n2")
'Yen
lblYen.Text = (decYen).ToString("n2")
```

I want to instead of using ("n2") use like ("c") but have it show up with a pound,euro, or yen sign instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the appropriate [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18sthszb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
lblPounds.Text = decPound.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))
lblEuros.Text = decEuro.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"))
lblYen.Text = decYen.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP"))
```

Result:

```
£61.35
77,52 €
¥10,526
```

Comment: awesome! do you know where i could get a list of the culture abbreviations for different countries?

Comment: I dont know if it is complete: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx but it seems as if. Remember to accept the answer(tick the green checkmark, [read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)).